# How to reset Fuji Xerox laser printer memory? (laser printers comes with fake toner level warning)

Tags: printer, laser-printer

I'm printer newbie. I have 2 models of Fuji Xerox printer: CP105b and Phaser 3124

When using CP105b for hundreds of printing output, the black toner level warning LED blinking. I refilled it with good toner powder until nearly full, and trying to continue printing. But the LED keeps blinking, even after I power off and on the printer. I just ignored the warning and print as usual.

After about 45 pages printed, a dialog box appeared force me to replace the cartridge, even the cartridge still has lots of toner powder. Apparently this printer model come with fake toner level warning.

Note: Some people told me, HP printers also comes with fake toner level warning. HP printers have memory which remember the cartridge serial number. It can remember only 2 different cartridge serial number.

So in order to reset HP printers memory, just use 3 different cartridge. When we use the third cartridge, the first cartridge serial number has been deleted.

How about Fuji Xerox? How to reset the memory?

Answer (score 1):

As per http://www.247inktoner.com/guide-to-resolving-printer-cartridge-problems

> Every cartridge contains a chip that is read by the printer when it is
>   installed. The chip informs the printer the type of cartridge it is,
>   how many pages have been printed from the cartridge so far and various
>   other diagnostic information. Many times, the chip is not successfully
>   read by the printer causing installation error messages. A cold
>   restart of the printer generally clears up these issues.

To perform a cold restart:

- While the printer is on, remove the toner cartridge from the printer.
- Power off the printer and completely disconnect the printer from all power sources. You can do this by unplugging the printer from the wall or unplugging the power cord from the back/side of the printer.
- While the printer is off, re-install the toner cartridge. Apply firm pressure to ensure the cartridge is completed seated in the printer.
- Wait 10 minutes from the time you unplugged the printer from all power sources. This will ensure the printer memory is completely cleared of any errors.
- Plug the printer back into the wall or back/side of the printer and turn the printer on.